# How do I expose a function in a Python module?

Tags: python, module, pypi

I wrote a module that consists of a single function. I'd like to be able to use it something like how tqdm works:

```
>>> from tqdm import tqdm
>>> tqdm
<function tqdm.tqdm>
```

However I can't figure out how to set things up this way. Here's what I have:

```
>>> from missingno import missingno
>>> missingno
<module 'missingno.missingno' from '[...]'>
>>> missingno.missingno
<function missingno.missingno.missingno>
```

I'm sure this has been asked countless times before, but I'm unsure of how packaging works and can't find an answer to this particular riddle.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at [pandas-profiling](https://github.com/JosPolfliet/pandas-profiling/blob/master/pandas_profiling/__init__.py) I've figured it out. Add the following line to `__init__.py()`:

`from .missingno import missingno`

Comment: Also if you want to be really super clean, add `__all__ = ['missingno']` in your `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question here, but I think what you want is:

```
from missingno.missingno import missingno
```

You might want to consider naming the package/file/function different things haha.

Comment: I want it be just `from missingno import missingno` though, as [tqdm](https://github.com/noamraph/tqdm) does. Trouble is that their repository seems to achieve this by placing the module at the top of repository (?) instead of in a module-level folder, but both pip and PyPi reject such a file structure.

Comment: You could write a script that performs an install to a separate location, and have your PYTHONPATH point at that location (i.e. when you install make a directory called "something" and put missingno.py in that directory. Then point PYTHONPATH to "something").

Comment: @ResMar no, `tqdm` does not place the module at the top of repo but inside a `tqdm` folder. Hence this can be misleading since the module folder has the same name as the top folder, but this is really a standard Python module hierarchy.